# Why 'a' convert to &nbsp

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have problem. I use wordpress and from yesterday do not work link
In database i have code:

```
<a href="dakjhd">text</a>
```

but in text editor in wordpress i have

```
&nbsp text &nbsp
```

I have no idea why a convert to &nbsp

Now i can't add link...

Please help

In step:

1. Add link to my text
2. I check in database this text and i see `<a href="dakjhd">text</a>`
3. I check in text editor this text and i see `&nbsp text &nbsp`
4. I don't know.

Comment: Probably the wordpress editor is set to block HTML code from being entered, and is filtering it out automatically as soon as it loads for security reasons.

Comment: your code uses strip_tags with htmlentites that is why.

Comment: hey, this documentation may help you http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is probably using [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove the tags from the actual HTML. You can use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to bring back it to its original form.

**Example:**

```
<?php

$link = '<a href="dakjhd">text</a>';

$a = strip_tags($link);
$b = htmlentities($link);
$c = html_entity_decode($b);

echo $a; // output: text
echo $b; //output: <a href="dakjhd">text</a>
echo $c; //output: the actual link

?>
```

Hope that clears your doubt!

Comment: ok thanks but this is wordpress and i don't know where is code to change :/